# How to determine if a functions return type is a primitive in ksp

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-symbol-processing

Short version: How can I tell if a `KSType` is a primitive or even compare it to a kotlin type?

I'm writing a code generator in Kotlin using ksp. I am iterating through a type's functions and have a `KSFunctionDeclaration`. I want to know if the return type of the function is a primitive.

I can see the name of the type using `it.returnType?.resolve()?.declaration?.simpleName` and that will show `Long` or `Int` etc. So I can just check if that name `== "Long"` etc. But it seems like there should be a way to compare to an actual type.

I found the `builtins` property on `Resolver` that has a property of type `KSType` for each built in type. But I don't know how to get to the `Resolver`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`builtIns` are the way to compare types and return types when it comes to primitives.

`Resolver` can be passed as argument to your visitors, it's totally safe.

```
class ConnectFunctionVisitor(
    private val environment: MySymbolProcessorEnvironment,
    private val resolver: Resolver
) : KSDefaultVisitor<KSFunctionDeclaration, FunSpec>()
```

For non-primitive types [you can use this extension](https://gist.github.com/NikolaDespotoski/5bbb254cf988a0f529a3385fc55114a7):

```
inline fun <reified T> KSType.isAssignableFrom(resolver: Resolver): Boolean {
    val classDeclaration = requireNotNull(resolver.getClassDeclarationByName<T>()) {
        "Unable to resolve ${KSClassDeclaration::class.simpleName} for type ${T::class.simpleName}"
    }
    return isAssignableFrom(classDeclaration.asStarProjectedType())
}
```